# Imputation conditional on other column values - Titanic dataset Age imputation conditional on Class and Sex

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am working on the Titanic dataset and want to impute for missing age values. I want to impute based on the Pclass and Sex - taking the average of all females in first class for missing female first class ages for example (obviously doing this for each class and both male and female).

I feel like something along the lines of df.groupby(['Pclass', 'Sex']) would work to group the Pclass and Sex then I could impute age based on these features.

I have also considered a loop to loop through class and sex columns but not sure how this would look.

I have not included code as all I have done up to this point is dropped the Cabin column and counted how many missing values there are using df.isna().sum().

Any suggestions of how to impute conditional on values contained in other columns would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

check this source for learning imputation of values

this article has helped me a lot

https://machinelearningmastery.com/handle-missing-data-python

Comment: Thanks for the link - it's a great article. But I can't find how to accomplish the task I have proposed in the question. I thought a bit more about how I could accomplish it in different programs and, essentially, I'm looking for a function analogous to =AVERAGEIFS() in excel, but in my case I want to be able to run different imputations if 'Pclass' and 'Sex' are given values.

Comment: i have also begun my journey on machine learning and using libraries so sorry i cant help you with that